# ios safari not updating precached files from sw workbox

Tags: ios, safari, mobile-safari, service-worker, workbox

I am building a PWA and generating the service worker with `workbox-sw`.

When a precached file is modified, the service worker updates and set the new revision hash in `indexedDB` but do not download the new version of the file.

So the service worker returns the old version of the precached file.

Browsers, other than Safari, download the new version of files that the revision hash has changed.

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue?